# How to get only date in a variable?

Tags: php, datetime

I have this date and time value Mar/10/2016 09:34:27am.

I want to get only the Mar/10/2016 to compare with today's date. My only concern is to split the date time to date only.

Comment: just use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your date format not changed and you only want pick date use this

```
$date = 'Mar/10/2016 09:34:27am';
echo current(explode(" ",$date));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your date value is going to be in format like "MM/DD/YYYY TIME" then i would suggest use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) like,

```
$datetime = "Mar/10/2016 09:34:27am"
$arr = explode(" ", $datetime);
echo $arr[0];   //will echo Mar/10/2016
```

Answer (score 0):

you try this code

```
$your_date="Mar/10/2016 09:34:27am";
$you_date=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($your_date));

 or 

$you_date=date('d-M-Y',strtotime($your_date));

or

$you_date=date('d/M/Y',strtotime($your_date));

or

$you_date=date('M/d/Y',strtotime($your_date));
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: id very simple you change `date('d',strtotime($your_date));`

Answer (score 0):

You can split your given date by `explode()` function . 
see-

```
$date = 'Mar/10/2016 09:34:27am';
echo  explode(" ",$date);
```